# Recorrer un array dentro de un objeto obtenido por una api

Tags: javascript-objeto

Si en mi api me viene un objeto así:

```
const artistas = [
  {
    nombre: "Ochoa Chang",
    solista: true,
    edad: 33,
    instrumento: "batería",
    paisNacimiento: "Mayotte",
    ultimoRecital: {
      pais: "Vatican City State (Holy See)",
      anio: 2016,
      entradasVendidas: 68197,
      costoEntradas: 2987,
    },
    discos: [
      {
        titulo: "pariatur excepteur dolore",
        canciones: 13,
        anioLanzamiento: 1993,
        copiasVendidas: 20393,
      }
    ]
  ]
```

¿Cómo recorro el segundo array de mi objeto?

Comment: Agrega por favor que hayas intentado, checa [ask] y como armar un [mcve]

Comment: El tipo de la variable `artistas` es un `Array`. Cada elemento de dicho `Array` se accede mediante un índice. Cada elemento además es un objeto, por lo cual podrías usar la sintaxis de punto para acceder al valor de algunos de sus campos. Por ejemplo si `elemento` es un elemento de tu `Array`, podrias acceder al campo llamado discos con: `elemento.discos`. En resumen: para acceder a cualquier elemento de  `artistas` debes indicar su índice, una vez que tienes el elemento, puedes acceder a sus propiedades usando la notación de punto. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Sabiendo que tienes dos arrays de objetos, simplemente puedes usar dos [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) anidados y acceder a la información de cada uno para mostrarla, así como el ejemplo a continuación:

```js
const artistas = [
  {
    nombre: "Ochoa Chang",
    solista: true,
    edad: 33,
    instrumento: "batería",
    paisNacimiento: "Mayotte",
    ultimoRecital: {
      pais: "Vatican City State (Holy See)",
      anio: 2016,
      entradasVendidas: 68197,
      costoEntradas: 2987,
    },
    discos: [
      {
        titulo: "pariatur excepteur dolore",
        canciones: 13,
        anioLanzamiento: 1993,
        copiasVendidas: 20393,
      }
    ]
  }
]
  
  artistas.forEach(item => {
    item.discos.forEach(disco => console.log(disco.titulo))
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un foreach [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
Esto puede ayudar a acceder a cada indice de tu array

```js
const artistas = [{
  nombre: "Ochoa Chang",
  solista: true,
  edad: 33,
  instrumento: "batería",
  paisNacimiento: "Mayotte",
  ultimoRecital: {
    pais: "Vatican City State (Holy See)",
    anio: 2016,
    entradasVendidas: 68197,
    costoEntradas: 2987,
  },
  discos: [{
    titulo: "pariatur excepteur dolore",
    canciones: 13,
    anioLanzamiento: 1993,
    copiasVendidas: 20393,
  }]
}]

artistas.forEach(element => console.log(element.ultimoRecital.pais));
```